# How to prevent docker containers from accessing my local network

Tags: docker, iptables, ebtables

I would like to be able to prevent docker containers connected to a bridge network from accessing my local network in order to add extra security since they will be accessible from outside (in case a container is compromised). I saw that I should probably use `ebtables` or the `physdev` module of `iptables` but I can't create a rule that works. Thanks to the one who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and if anyone is interested, it is possible to use ebtables.

```sh
# Authorize DNS queries
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPV4 --ip-protocol TCP --ip-destination-port 53 --ip-destination 192.168.1.1 --ip-source 172.18.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPV4 --ip-protocol UDP --ip-destination-port 53 --ip-destination 192.168.1.1 --ip-source 172.18.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
# Drop all others packets
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPV4 --ip-destination 192.168.1.0/24 --ip-source 172.18.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

Do not forget to replace the `172.18.0.0/16` subnet with the one on which your containers are connected.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumbling through this myself and found one solution was to insert (`-I`) a new rule into the `DOCKER-USER` chain.

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73994723/20189349