# How to disable all network connections inside Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming, docker, iptables

I'd like to restrict any network communications from inside a docker container.
I've seen these SO questions: 
[How to prevent code inside docker container from accessing the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610618/how-to-prevent-code-inside-docker-container-from-accessing-the-network)
[Disable access to LAN from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207397/disable-access-to-lan-from-docker-container)
But modifications in `iptables` did not take any effect.

1. How could I specify `--icc=false` option? I try to `docker run --icc=false -t -i distr` and docker does not understand `icc` option. Should I specify it somewhere else?
2. Is there any solid method to disable networking? Like downing `docker0` interface and making sure it will not get up again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `--icc=false` flag is for the Docker daemon; it is applied system wide, not to single containers.

I think specifying `--net=none` to the `docker run` command will do what you want; it won't connect the container to the Docker bridge so the container will be unable to communicate to the outside world or other containers.

Comment: Additionally, `--icc-false` would only prevent inter-container communication, it won't block access to anything else

Comment: how can i use this with docker-compose?

Comment: @IshanKhare Please just look at the docs. There is a `network_mode` option that probably does what you want. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode